# The CDF of an i.i.d. sample realizations

Tags: probability, statistics

Is it possible to draw the CDF of the empirical measure $\hat{P}_x$ for a i.i.d. sample realizations where $X_1 = 0.3$,$X_2 = 5$,$X_3 = 1.5$, $X_4 = 3.4$ without knowing the distribution?

Comment: @did do we assume that each value has a 25% probability of occurence? thanks

Comment: Wikipedia gives [10 different ways of estimating the quantiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_the_quantiles_of_a_population)

Comment: ok I now I see what should be the correct way

Comment: thanks @did. how can I approve your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: the empirical CDF depends only on the sample (this is what *empirical* refers to), here the set of values 0.3, 5, 1.5, 3.4. Even the *order* in which these values appeared is lost in the empirical CDF.

> > do we assume that each value has a 25% probability of occurence?

The empirical distribution puts mass k/n on each value, where k is the number of times said value appeared in the sample of size n. In your case, n=4 and the values are all different hence yes, each gets a weight 1/4.